# mechanize browser has no attribute

Tags: python, attributes, mechanize

I've re written this twice, I can't see the problem,i've got mechanize installed on python 2 and I'm not doing both tabs and spaces, i'm only doing spaces.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urlparse
import mechanize

url = "http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)

for link in br.links():
    print link
```

and the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mechanize.py", line 4, in <module>
    import mechanize
  File "/home/ro/Autoblog/mechanize/mechanize.py", line 8, in <module>
    br = mechanize.Browser()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Browser'
```

Comment: Is `/home/ro/Autoblog/mechanize/mechanize.py` the path to `mechanize` or is it shadowing the real module?

Comment: yeah, that was the problem, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filename of your Python file is "mechanize.py" (/home/ro/Autoblog/mechanize/mechanize.py).  This shadows the name of the "mechanize" module.  Because of this namespace collision, you are actually importing your own script when you do: `import mechanize`.

Change the name of your "mechanize.py" script to something else and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a confilcting file and this is coming from the github where you downloaded the mechanize, there are two _mechanize.py in each mechanize folder so, delete one mechanize folder that is the second mechanize folder that is inside a mechanize folder